# Pandas - Calculate aggregate value for last 1 year

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in this form:

```
Customer_key    Issue_dt      Amount
45435           2021-03-19    566
64352           2021-06-22    843
43766           2020-04-29    754
45435           2021-06-21    547
```

There are many repeated customer_keys for different Issue_dt. I want to groupby customer_key and get the total Amount only for year 2021. Can someone please suggest, how to do that ??

Comment: filter, then apply your transform

Comment: If you think filter by `2021` then closed is correct (100% match), if need previous year from actual then it is not dupe, only similar (70% in my opinion). Can you specify it?

Answer (score 0):

If need filter by year use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df[df['Issue_dt'].dt.year == 2021].groupby('customer_keys', as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
```

For dynamic solution get actual year and subtract `1`:

```
y = pd.to_datetime('now').year - 1
df[df['Issue_dt'].dt.year == y].groupby('customer_keys', as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_key':[45435,64352,43766,45435], 'Issue_dt': ['2021-03-19','2021-06-22','2020-04-29','2021-06-21'], 'Amount': [566, 843, 754, 547]})
               
df[pd.to_datetime(df['Issue_dt']).dt.year==2021].groupby('Customer_key').sum()
```

First filter df by year (after type conversion) then apply sum on groups.

Comment: So your solution is same like me, only converting to datetimes?

Comment: Actually, I did not see yours. When I started coding there was not any answer there! Yes, they are the same.

Comment: ya, when posted there was solution 5 minutes. It it is long or not it is for discussion ;)